# SharePoint - eChat - Is it possible to create a live Q&A in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a requirement to create live q&a sessions in sharepoint.

The requirement is for people to post questions and for the leader to answer them. Making all responses from the leader visible to all.

Is there a way to do this in SharePoint, and if so how can it be done?

My knowledge of sharepoint developer is not strong.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Can you use javascript to help?

Comment: You may want to look at this question, and see if it helps you better ask your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485527/how-to-programmatically-update-content-in-a-sharepoint-web-part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is "not strong" in your case. Without coding skills, you could use a sub-list feature. Create lists named "Questions" and "Answers", and follow up with a tutorial:

http://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/sharepoint-list-parent-child-relationship-e-g-creating-list-b-items-from-list-a/